# JSF Composite Component

Tags: jsf, composite-component

I'm trying to create a composite component for use in my Seam application, and I'm running into problems with the simplest "hello, world" component.

I have placed a file named hello.xhtml in {jboss deploy}/application.ear/application.war/resources/greet :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">
<head>
<title>My First Composite Component</title>
</head>
<body>

<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="who"/>
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <h:outputText value="Hello, #{cc.attrs.who}!"/>
</composite:implementation>

</body>
</html>
```

Now in home.xhtml, located at the root of my webapp ({jboss deploy}/application.ear/application.war/home.xhtml):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
            xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
            xmlns:g="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/greet"
            xmlns:s="http://jboss.com/products/seam/taglib"
            template="layout/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
    <div id="content">
        <g:hello who="World"/>
        <br/>
    </div>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

But my "hello, world" is not displayed, and I dont get any error messages, even when I turn on debug level logging for com.sun and javax.faces categories.

I've verified that the resources directory is in the proper place, since adding the directory resources/images/test.jpg, then adding this to home.xhtml:

```
h:graphicImage value="#{resource['images:test.jpg']}"/>
```

Results in the image being displayed. I just don't know why JSF isn't picking up my xhtml file from the greet directory.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting it into `META-INF/resources`, not just `resources`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I have tried all the following locations with no luck:
`application.ear/META-INF/resources
`application.ear/application.war/WEB-INF/resources
`application.ear/application.war/WEB-INF/classes/resources
`application.ear/application.war/META-INF/resources (completely non-standard)

I'm concerned that I get no debug/info output for this. I have no idea where JSF/Seam is looking for the resource directory.

Comment: Try application.ear/application.war/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/resources. I don't have experience with the application.ear part, but here's an example of a webapp using a composite component: http://confluence.highsource.org/x/FoBM. The component xhtml is in war/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/resources.

Also make sure that you're using JSF 2.0, not JSF 1.2. And no, you're not getting any error messages, non-processed namespaces are treated in a "lax" way.

Comment: Unfortunately that location doesnt work either. The JSF2 resource location is being seen properly - I updated the original post to show that I can reference resources such as the 'images' library. But the composite component is not seen.

Comment: @purecharger: I'd try deploying the webapp as WAR first of all to check if the problem is in ear step. I can't spot any problems with your code. The namespace seems to be allright. But maybe I'm missing something. Are you sure your "content" fragment is inserted at all?

Comment: Lexicore, thanks for your suggestions. I think I figured out the root of my problem: Seam does not work well with JSF 2.0. The faces-config.xml for my app (and all seam examples) specified JSF 1.2. Attempting to use JSF 2.0 causes exceptions on startup.

Comment: Yes, I suspected JSF 1.2 since I know that Richfaces 3.x does not run on JSF 2.0. Good luck further on.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of login composite component where also jsf2 resources are explained:
http://jugojava.blogspot.com/2011/09/jsf-composite-component-binding-to.html